# Prove that a demomposited map is null-homotopic

Tags: general-topology

Let $p: S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^2$ be the two-fold covering map and let $f: X \rightarrow S^2$ be a continuous map from some topological space $X$ to $S^2$. Suppose the map
$$
p \circ f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^2
$$
is null-homotopic. Show that $f$ itself is also null-homotopic.
$$$$
From the statement, I think we need to use homotopy lifting theorem, but I don't know how to link this with null-homotopic maps. May I ask do we use homotopy lifting theorem here to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: We can take an homotopy of $p\circ f$ to constant map and lift to an homotopy of $f$ to constant map...  Can we?

Comment: @BobDobbs I still don't much understand, could you please give more details? Thanks!

Comment: I must recall this theorem myself again. Maybe later I write. I gave up alg. top. nowadays.  I can't tag your name by the way.

Comment: Start by reviewing the statement of the homotopy-lifting property. What does it tell you in this situation?